How to resolve `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured` error regarding 'BlogProject.urls'?
I'm encountering a django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured error in my Django project. When I check the cron.log file using tail -f /var/log/cron.log, I see the following error message:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 748, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'BlogProject.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.


My crontab content is as follows:
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python /usr/src/BlogProject/manage.py flushexpiredtokens > /var/log/cron.log 2>&1.

I have a urls.py file where I define URL patterns for my Django project. Below is the content of the file:
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users.views import RegisterView

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
        path("", include("users.urls")),
        path("", include("blogger.urls")),
        path("", include("administration.urls")),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

settings.py file contains the configuration settings for my Django project. Below is the content of the file:
from celery.schedules import crontab
import os
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = ""

DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=0))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"

SITE_ID = 1

WEBSITE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    # JWT configuration
}

# Other configurations...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Installed apps...
    'django_crontab',  # Django Crontab
]

# Other configurations...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # Database configuration...
    }
}

# Password validation and other configurations...

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

STATIC_URL = "static/"

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


Have you tried looking at the BlogProjects.urls file and following the advice given in the error message?

I fixed everything that could cause circular importing and updated my urls.py file as you instructed. This time, I'm not getting the error anymore, but the 'flushexpiredtokens' command, which I intend to use with crontab, is not working. Could it be that I made a mistake while adding this? My goal is simply to delete expired tokens.
